# Why does Fmodel Error occur? How to use Fmodel function?

Tags: r, machine-learning, rpart

Regarding Fmodel Error in R

Hi, I'm beginner of R programming.

Now, I'm studying rpart pacakage to apply it to workplace

when i put code "fmodel", occurs error "could not find function "fmodel"

How to use this funcion? do i have to download some package?

thanks

Input

```
library(rpart)
model_2 <- rpart(Q1_UA~ E7_LABEL+PRMT_LABEL+SDRA, data=test2, cp=0.002)
fmodel(model_2, ~ E7_LABEL+PRMT_LABEL+SDRA)
```

Console

```
fmodel(model_1, ~ E7_LABEL+PRMT_LABEL+SDRA)
Error in fmodel(model_1, ~E7_LABEL + PRMT_LABEL + SDRA) : 
  could not find function "fmodel"
```

Comment: `fmodel` is not from `rpart`. Maybe you need to install `statisticalModeling`?

Answer (score 1):

As hinted in the comments, `fmodel` is not part of the `rpart` package - you can see the available functions of `rpart` package [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rpart/versions/4.1-13), and confirm that `fmodel` is not included.

`fmodel` comes from the `statisticalModeling` package - see the relevant [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/statisticalModeling/versions/0.3.0/topics/fmodel); so, you would need to install & import this package first before anything:

```
install.packages('statisticalModeling')
library(statisticalModeling)
```